# iOS/PHP kCCDecodeError

Tags: php, ios, encryption

I can't for the life of me work out why when I encrypt something in PHP I can't then decrypt it in my iOS app, but PHP can decrypt iOS encrypted strings and decrypt/encrypt between itself.

> PHP -> Obj-C FAILS.

Yes, I have looked across the net and the only solution I found was to use `CBC` in `PHP` which I'm already doing.

I'm using the `FBEncryptor` library for iOS and these are the encrypt/decrypt functions in PHP:

```
function encrypt($decrypted)
{    
    $iv = ''; for($i=0;$i<16;$i++){ $iv .= "\0";}
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $passKey, $decrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    return $ciphertext;
}

function decrypt($encrypted)
{
    $iv = ''; for($i=0;$i<16;$i++){ $iv .= "\0";}        
    $ciphertext = base64_decode($encrypted);
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $passKey, $ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return $plaintext;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out the problem. Was a silly mistake on my part with the pass key variable. Here is my final implementation anyway for anyone else that comes across this problem:

```
function encrypt($decrypted)
{
    $thePassKey = "12345678901234567890123456789012";

    # Add PKCS7 padding.
    $str = $decrypted;
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    if (($pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block)) < $block) 
    {
        $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = ''; for($i=0;$i<$iv_size;$i++){ $iv .= "\0";}
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $thePassKey, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}

function decrypt($encrypted)
{
    $thePassKey = "12345678901234567890123456789012";

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = ''; for($i=0;$i<$iv_size;$i++){ $iv .= "\0";}
    $str = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $thePassKey, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    # Strip PKCS7 padding.
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = ord($str[($len = strlen($str)) - 1]);
    if ($pad && $pad < $block && preg_match(
        '/' . chr($pad) . '{' . $pad . '}$/', $str))
    {
        return substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - $pad);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [FBEncryptor](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor) Github page (emphasis mine):

> Supported encryption algorithm is **AES 256 bit only**.

But in your code snippet above, you're doing:

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

i.e. decrypting with AES 128 bit as your cipher.

You'll need to correct your code accordingly. Other common mistakes include using mismatched padding and block cipher operation modes.

Comment: Yet somehow encrypting in iOS with 256 bit I can decrypt in PHP using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128. The problem is iOS can't decrypt something from PHP. I'll try switch to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 but I think I tried this and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Also looking at the FBEncryptor code it is using kCCBlockSizeAES128 and kCCAlgorithmAES128 but uses kCCKeySizeAES256, which from understanding correlates to using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 with a 16 byte IV and a 32 byte key - which is what the PHP code is using :/