# PHP AES256 Encryption => RNCryptor RNDecryptor returns blank / HMAC Mismatch

Tags: php, ios, encryption, aes, rncryptor

Using PHP 5.4 (mcrypt), RNCryptor 2, iOS 6.

PHP function creates base64 with all headers as referenced from https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/wiki/Data-Format.

PHP decrypt function which can decrypt base64 string from both RNEncryptor and the PHP Encrypt function below return data as expected.

When using RNDecryptor with base64 from PHP Encrypt function below, no data is returned as shown in XCode output below.

PHP Function:

```
function encrypt($data, $key)
{
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $salt = '12345678';

    $_key = $this->pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $salt, 10000, 32, true);

    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $_key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    $hmac = $this->pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $salt, 10000, 32, true);

    $data = mb_convert_encoding(chr(1).chr(0).$salt.$salt.$iv.$ciphertext.$hmac, "BASE64", "UTF-8");

    return $data;
}
```

PHP Function Call:

```
encrypt('My Data', 'mykey');
```

iOS:

```
NSError * error;
NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:[NSString base64DataFromString:@"AQBpcGhvbmU2MmlwaG9uZTYyrYk2rJnaoywktnx6TZ4X3YKgYuEHCL1EHv+/MqIvQMq5BmZOyMJr QSRs9P4uxShsOJOg67VYniUGhHbFNTSl1Q=="]
                                    withPassword:@"mykey"
                                           error:&error];

NSLog(@"data = %@, %@", decryptedData, error);
```

XCode output:

> data = <>, (null)

This is done when I comment out HMAC verification in RNDecryptor -finish, once these section is uncommented I receive a HMAC Mismatch error

> data = (null), Error Domain=net.robnapier.RNCryptManager Code=1 "HMAC Mismatch" UserInfo=0x1e564280 {NSLocalizedDescription=HMAC Mismatch}

```
if (self.hasHMAC) {
  NSMutableData *HMACData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:self.HMACLength];
  CCHmacFinal(&_HMACContext, [HMACData mutableBytes]);

  if (![HMACData isEqualToData:self.inData]) {
    [self cleanupAndNotifyWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:kRNCryptorErrorDomain
                                                        code:kRNCryptorHMACMismatch
                                                    userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"HMAC Mismatch"
                                                                                         forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]]];
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK : mb_convert_encoding is for transformation between different charsets. BASE64 is not a charset. Its a transfer encoding. Do you know base64_decode()? Try it instead of mb_convert_encoding.

Comment: Changed to base64_encode() on PHP side and still get HMAC Mismatch from RNDecryptor iOS side.

Comment: What does `var_dump($salt, $iv, $ciphertext, $hmac);` say?

Comment: Is the base64 output any different if you use `base64_encode()` than if you use `mb_convert_encoding()`?

Comment: var_dump => string(8) "iphone62" string(16) "ÆÒi  ïœábÕ”LYuã" string(16) "§¡GÌj*blÇKç,/ôr" string(32) "¹fNÈÂkA$lôþ.Å(l8“ ëµXž%„vÅ54¥Õ"

Comment: Ok. (they are not empty). Sorry that I cannot help further as I have no test environment for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to both an incorrect HMAC (was passing the HMAC Key) and PHP encryption needing PKCS7 Padding on the data to be encrypted (not the IV too).

Final PHP function...

```
function AES256Encrypt($data, $key)
{
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = $block - (strlen($data) % $block);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $keySalt = '12345678';
    $hmacSalt = '12345678';

    $_key = $this->pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $keySalt, 10000, 32, true);
    $_hmacKey = $this->pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $hmacSalt, 10000, 32, true);

    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $_key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    $data = base64_encode(chr(1).chr(0).$keySalt.$hmacSalt.$iv.$ciphertext.hash_hmac('SHA256',$ciphertext,$_hmacKey, true));
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: It just uses the standard [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) library.

Comment: I know, but I'm asking about the parameters you passed to this library
..
Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2):

`mb_convert_encoding()` will do base64 conversion, but it will output *chunked* base64.

The PHP base64 decoder will accept both chunked and unchunked, but iOS...?

Perhaps you need to just encode:

```
$data = base64_encode(chr(1).chr(0).$salt.$salt.$iv.$ciphertext.$hmac);
```

You may want to check out [iOS/PHP kCCDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300147/ios-php-kccdecodeerror)  for another implementation.

Finally, from the [RNCryptor Wiki](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/wiki/Data-Format) Data Format, I see (together with a link to [the PHP implementation on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000843/retrieve-iv-from-rncryptor-aes-256-header-in-php/13785706#13785706))

> HMAC is generated using the ciphertext and the HMACKey (above) and the SHA-256 PRF.

...but the HMAC you append seems to me to actually be the HMACKey, not the HMAC...?

Comment: As I replied to hek2mgl, I changed to base64_encode() and still get HMAC Mismatch. The space in "descryptData:" is from the base64 output from PHP.

Comment: I don't get it -- literally: my output does not have that space. Testing with PHP 5.3.15 from command line. Try removing the space by hand, just to check.

Comment: "_Is the base64 output any different if you use base64_encode() than if you use mb_convert_encoding()?_" - Yes, mb_convert_encoding() adds a space. The snippet of Cocoa you quoted was with mb_convert_encoding(), since then I have entered the base64_encode() string and still get HMAC errors.

Comment: Looks like another user had similar problems: added link in answer.

Comment: Had a read and implemented his padding although RNCryptor still reports a HMAC Mismatch error. iOS "CCHmacInit" seems to be producing a different HMAC to that passed to it, I have logged the keys and original HMAC it has got from the decoded base64 and these all relate back to the PHP. I will update my original question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you generate the same encoded packet in iOS? By checking the two strings, you might gather some insight as to where the mismatch lies.

Comment: I might have found something, updating answer.

Comment: Yes that would make sense! I encrypted the same string with the same key from both RNCryptor and PHP and the base64 strings were different, although the PHP decrypt function decrypted them both perfectly (However warned of HMAC mismatch). So the variance would be the HMAC and HMAC Key. Would it be hash_hmac('SHA256', $ciphertext, $HMACKey); ? I will give it a shot

Comment: Brilliant! Finally got rid of the HMAC Mismatch error with `return base64_encode(chr(1).chr(0).$salt.$salt.$iv.$ciphertext.hash_hmac('SHA256',$ciphertext,$hmac, true));`, thanks! Changed the PHP decrypt function too and now matches HMAC on PHP side too. _However_ the data is still returning empty on iOS...